# SharePoint online Unable to get property 'onDismiss' of undefined or null reference

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I randomly receive the error below on Office 365 SharePoint online when I go to a document library or custom list or trying to add a new item.

Something went wrong.
Unable to get property 'onDismiss' of undefined or null reference.

When I look at developer tools, I see this .js file being referenced splistitemsscope-is-mini-<>.js
Not sure where to begin to troubleshoot. Is anyone else getting this odd message?

Comment: Are you using custom power apps form ?

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem as well after migrate a list from SharePoint online to another SharePoint online teamsroom.
Cannot add a new element and also not edit an element.